# I can not find tools.jar in jdk1.8.0_101

Tags: java-8

I have just re-installed my computer and when i tried to setup my working environment.
I've tried to use maven build in my computer, but i always met the ERROR:

> [ERROR] C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_101..\lib\tools.jar

Actually, i could not find tools.jar file in JAVA_HOME 
I make sure that I already downloaded jdk (not jre) and setup JAVA_HOME (C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_101) correctly.

> ps: my jdk's download link: 
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Does anyone know about my issue?

Thanks again for any help.

Thanks again for any help.

**Solution found**, see my answer below.,

see my answer below.

Comment: FWIW For OpenJDK (1.8.0.101) it's under "$JAVA_HOME/lib"

Comment: which editor you are using ? eclipse?

Comment: The path doesn't look correct. There shouldn't be a `..` There is something wrong with your JAVA_HOME I suspect.

Comment: I set JAVA_HOME=C:\\Java\jdk1.8_101 folder.

Comment: In JAVA_HOME\lib folder. I dont find tools.jar file

Comment: I've used eclipse

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong on my OS.
My issue was solved after i re-installed jdk with default folder.
 my jdk folder is:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101